# GoLang Level3 embedded struct initialisation

Tags: go, golangci-lint

I am new to Golang development. I was trying to initialize a struct which has a level 3 embedded struct. I can create till 2 levels, but when I try with level 3, it gives me this compile time error.

*missing type in composite literal*

Here is the trial code
available. Please help/suggest an excellent way to achieve the same.

In main.go, unable to initialise a2 variable.

```
package main

import (
    "structpackage"
    cfmt "basic/utils"
    "fmt"

)

type p StrPackage
type n NestedStruct

type Address struct {
    Name         string
    city         string
    Pincode      int
    StrPackage   p // embedded struct
    NestedStruct n // nested struct embedded in Address struct
}

func main() {

    
    // Declaring and initializing a struct using a struct literal
    a1 := Address{Name: "Akshay", city: "Dehradun", Pincode: 3623572, StrPackage: p{14, "Software engineer"}} // embedded struct implementation

    /** * embedded struct implementation Start  **/

    a2 := Address{Name: "Akshay", city: "Dehradun", Pincode: 3623572, NestedStruct: n{Designation: "Software engineer", S: {Age: 12, Occuption: "sfdsf"}}} // Naming fields while initializing a struct

    fmt.Println("Address2: ", a2)
}
```

structpackage.go

```
package structpackage

type StrPackage struct {
    Age       int
    Occuption string
}

type NestedStruct struct {
    Designation string
    S           StrPackage
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that an object of type Strpackage needs to be **constructed** on the fly and assigned to NestedStruct.S

```
a2 := Address{
         Name: "Akshay", 
         city: "Dehradun", 
         Pincode: 3623572, 
         NestedStruct: n{
            Designation: "Software engineer", 
            S: structpackage.StrPackage{
                  Age: 12, Occuption: 
                  "sfdsf"
            }
         }
     }
```